# Android FusedLocationProvider returns null if no internet connection available

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi

The Title says most of it:
I use the FusedLocationProvider which works perfect if there is a internet connection.

If no connection is present (no sim card, no wifi connection but wifi turned on) everything returns null, even the getLastLocation().

The Api-connection for the request is successful.

Is there a solution or do i have to use the old location manager?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself and it is pretty obvious. 
I am using my phone indoor and the GPS-receiver just has a serious problem to get a location fix -> of course, it is indoor. It CAN get a location fix, but it is not always possible.

So it is not the problem of the FusedLocationProvider, it does works offline as well, but then without cell-tower or wifi location.